# TCL regsub isn't working when the expression has [0]

Tags: regex, tcl

I tried the following code:

```
set exp {elem[0]}
set temp {elem[0]}

regsub $temp $exp "1" exp

if {$exp} {
    puts "######### 111111111111111 ################"
} else {
    puts "########### 0000000000000000 ############"
}
```

of course, this is the easiest regsub possible (the words match completely), and still it doesnt work, and no substitution is done. if I write elem instead of elem[0], everything works fine.
I tried using {elem[0]}, elem[0], "elem[0]" etc, and none of them worked.
Any clue anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > This is the easiest regsub possible (the words match completely)

Actually, no, the words don't match. You see, in a regular expression, square brackets have meaning. Your expression `{elem[0]}` actually mean:

```
match the sequence of letters 'e'
                  followed by 'l'
                  followed by 'e'
                  followed by 'm'
                  followed by '0' (the character for the number zero)
```

So it would match the string "elem0" not "elem[0]" since the character after 'm' is not '0'.

What you want is `{elem\[0\]}` <-- backslash escapes special meaning.

Read the manual for tcl's regular expression syntax, [re_syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), for more info on how regular expressions work in tcl.

Comment: At least link to the documentation for the current release: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: @Glenn: Done. It's now pointing to 8.5. Though, I believe the re_syntax haven't changed at all.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @slebetman's answer, if your want any special characters in your regular expression to be treated like plain text, there is special syntax for that:

```
set word {abd[0]}
set regex $word
regexp $regex $word        ;# => returns 0, did not match
regexp "(?q)$regex" $word  ;# => returns 1, matched
```

That `(?q)` marker must be the first part of the RE.

Also, if you're really just comparing literal strings, consider the simpler `if {$str1 eq $str2} ...` or the glob-style matching of [`[string match]`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40)

Comment: I'd use `***=$regex` here; I find that a bit more mnemonic (YMMV).